# Convert from IList to List<T>

Tags: c#, wpf, list

I know this question has been answered but I've tried many of the solutions and none of them work.

I have a chart that binds to an IList of objects after a series has been selected, but I'm having trouble converting from IList to List; the list ends up empty with my casting:

```
public class ChartData
{
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public int Year { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; } 
}

public IList BindSelectedItems
{
    get 
    { 
        return _bindSelectedItems; 
    }
    set
    {
        _bindSelectedItems = value;

        //Solutions I found that don't work:
        IList<ChartData> myList = value.OfType<ChartData>().ToList();
        //IList<ChartData> myList = value.Cast<ChartData>().ToList();

        List<ChartData> cd = myList as List<ChartData>;

        foreach (var c in cd) //does not work b/c myList is empty
        {
            Debug.Print("type is " + c.Type + " cost is " + c.Value + " year is " + c.Year);
        }

        RaisePropertyChanged("BindSelectedItems");
    }
}

IList _bindSelectedItems;
```

Comment: What was *is* the type of the data within `_bindSelectedItems`? It would really help if you'd show a short but complete program demonstrating the problem. What happens if you use Cast instead of OfType? Why are you using `as` for `cd`, rather than just `List<ChartData> list = value.Cast<ChartData>().ToList();`?

Comment: Are you positive that you have items in your list?  The version of the code you have uncommented would be throwing an exception if an item in your list couldn't be cast to your `ChartData` class.

Comment: Yes, "BindSelectedItems" is also bound to a GridControl as an ItemsSource and I can see the list of returned data after I click on the series.

Comment: A better question, may be where is this data coming from? If it exists on another control...why not setup a binding in Xaml? ???

Comment: @Will Why did you remove the `WPF` tag? The user specified WPF and this is a WPF Issue.

Comment: @OmegaMan it has nothing to do with WPF.  Yeah, his application is WPF, but this is about casting a non-generic collection to a generic one or vise versa.

Comment: There is no casting going on here.  OfType does not cast.

Comment: public IList BindSelectedItems is not even valid syntax.  That won't even compile.

Comment: @Blam, for some reason only public IList BindSelectedItems will return the correct data. I also tried public object BindSelectedItems, which also returns  the correct data to the GridControl but I'd like to have a List as the end result.

Comment: I am not buying that public IList BindSelectedItems  compiles on your machine.  A type argument is required.

Comment: @Blam IList is the type.  Go try it yourself.

Comment: I did try it myself and IList and IList requires a type.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5y536ey6.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized I could not achieve what I was doing binding to an IList and have to use and ObservableCollection as follows:

```
    ObservableCollection<object> _bindSelectedItems;
    public ObservableCollection<object> BindSelectedItems
    {
        get { return _bindSelectedItems; }
        set
        {

            _bindSelectedItems = value;
            _bindSelectedItems.CollectionChanged += _bindSelectedItems_CollectionChanged;
            RaisePropertyChanged("BindSelectedItems");
        }
    }

    void _bindSelectedItems_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ObservableCollection<object> items = sender as ObservableCollection<object>;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is within the signature of the binding target. You are binding to an `IList`, do you want to expose a holder/wrapper for a collection to be bound to? I believe you want to bind to the data actually and *not its wrapper*.

Bind to `IList<ChartData>` instead so the binding operations can reflect off of `ChartData` objects which is the ultimate target..

---

```
public IList<ChartData> BindSelectedItems
{
    get 
    { 
        return _bindSelectedItems; 
    }
    set
    {
        _bindSelectedItems = value;

        RaisePropertyChanged("BindSelectedItems");
    }
}

IList<ChartData> _bindSelectedItems;
```

Comment: I tried that and "value" returned a NullReferenceException

Comment: @AC did you change the signature of the property to `IList<ChartData>` ?

Comment: @AC Can you distill this problem into a basic example outside of your main application? If so it might shed some light on the problem; something else is going on and from my vantage point, I can't see it. If you can create an easier example, and provide it on the post, it may lead to an answer.